No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) while using FTP
I have created an EC2 instance and it's working. I have created the FTP users and passwords successfully. Now while connecting FTP using FileZilla. I am getting below error
Command:    open "ftphyb@ec2-3-8-24-114.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com" 22
Status:         Using username "ftphyb". 
Status:         Server refused our key 
Status:         Server refused our key 
Status:         Server refused our key 
Status:         Server refused our key 
Error:          FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Could not connect to server

Any Idea what is the issue?
The above IP details and FTP are wrong and it's only for demo purposes.

You are, in fact, not using FTP. You are using SFTP. FTP is unencrypted and is to be considered absolutely legacy and not for any serious use.
You are trying to transfer files to your server via port 22 (sshd), which is to be considered a secure (encrypted) modern way of doing uploads.
firstly try to simply log into the server with ssh.
ssh ftphyb@ec2-3-8-24-114.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com

This will probably give you a similar error.
You need to upload your public key to the server for login.
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ftphyb@ec2-3-8-24-114.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com

The server clearly states it only accepts a pubkey login
